# NAT rule redirection with Pfctl over VPN

Tags: network, vpn, firewall, pfctl

I'm trying to configure a NAT redirection with Pfctl on my macOS (Ventura 13.2). I want to achieve a redirection for a specific IP and port to another IP (which is reachable through VPN) and the same port, more specifically:

`rdr pass on utun3 inet proto tcp from any to 10.0.0.3 port = 6443 -> <OTHER_IP> port 6443`

My first question is if this is the correct rule for this approach.

As you can notice, I'm using the utun3 interface, as it's the VPN interface that receives an IP when the VPN is active. There are other `utun<x>` interfaces as well so I believe this is the proper interface to configure.

I've enabled `net.inet.ip.forwarding: 1`, and I'm trying to set the rule above in `/etc/pf.conf`.

I create a custom anchor in `/etc/pf.anchors/custom_anchor` and loaded in the `pf.conf` but with no luck, I could not get any ouput that the rule was loaded from `sudo pfctl -sr`.

Then I tried to place it under `rdr-anchor "com.apple/*"` and have reloaded the pfctl.

However, after adding this rule and reloading pfctl, I'm not able to see the rules being loaded when I run `sudo pfctl -sr`. Here is the output:

```
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
scrub-anchor "com.apple/*" all fragment reassemble
anchor "com.apple/*" all
```

And here is the output of `sudo pfctl -a com.apple -sr`:

```
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
anchor "200.AirDrop/*" all
anchor "250.ApplicationFirewall/*" all
```

The `sudo pfctl -si` command shows that the pf service is running.

Are there any other relevant configurations or steps that I should be aware of? I appreciate any assistance with this issue. Thanks!